# What does add Gauss Random Noise mean?

Tags: matlab, uniform-distribution, noise

I'm reading a article about LSSVM and in numerical part they created an artificial example and it says:
The two features of samples are uniformly distrubuted in $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$ with 50% of Gauss random noise for positive and negative class respectively. In this way our data set will be almost separable.

I was trying to reproduce this example in MATLAB, however, I don't know what "with 50% of Gauss random noise" mean, in order to understand it I google it and I discovered the commands `awgn`and `wgn` in Matlab but I can't understand what all arguments do. I continued looking for answers and I find that a possible interpretation is

```
pos = rand(2,10) + 0.5randn(2,10) 
pos = 2*rand(2,10) + 0.5randn(2,10)
```

is it right? Is there a reference to understand more about gauss radom noise?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about a simple linear regression model,

Y = BX + e

where e is the random error, we often say that e is assumed to follow a Normal (Gaussian) distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

This is what we mean by noise. Noise is basically the process that adds variability to the data. We call it noise because it distorts the signal from the underlying function (Y = BX).

Depending on the model that you have, or the data you are working with, your noise may take on different distributions.

Comment: $Y = BX + e$ you have a source from $e$ right? In linear regression the source is the distance between the line and points,  so How can I produce $e$ for my special case? is it right what I have done?